# Reactでpeformance.getEntriesByTypeを利用してブラウザの戻るボタンが押されたときにリロードしようと考えたが、前述の関数の戻り値が想定されるものと異なっている

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-jsx

下記のようにすると `perfEntries` に `PerformanceNavigationTiming` クラスのオブジェクトが格納されるはずだが、 `PerformanceEntry` クラスのオブジェクトが格納されてしまい、2行目で "type属性は存在しません" というエラーが出ています。

環境はTypeScript+Reactです。

```
const perfEntries = window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
const Ltype = perfEntries[0].type;
```

※2024/02/07修正

Answer (score 0):

1行目の `[0].type` が不要なのだと思います。

`performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")` が `PerformanceNavigationTiming` のリスト、`performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]` が `PerformanceNavigationTiming` のインスタンス、`performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type` は文字列です。

---

Typescrirpt のエラーですね。
`perfEntries[0]` を `PerformanceNavigationTiming` か `any` にキャストする必要があります。

Comment: すみません
一行目の```[0].type```は削除ミスです。
これをなくすと上記で述べたエラーが出現します。
修正しました。

Comment: 回答が意味不明になるような質問文の変更は、元のテキストを残して追記していただけると嬉しいです。なんにせよ、別の回答を追記しました。

Comment: @int32_tさん　回答ありがとうございます。質問文の変更に関しては次回以降気をつけたいと思います。また、キャストは試して見ようと思います